# what is the probability of this event?

Tags: probability, dice

given this outcome of the dice {2, 3, 4, 6, 6}. You decide to re-roll both sixes. What is the probability that you roll either a small straight (four dice are in a row) or a large straight (all five dice are in a row)?

Comment: A complete analysis of this game is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154519.  It includes code to compute all probabilities of this nature.